# Why did my balance return to Zero after stopping Geth? (newbie)

Tags: balances

I am a complete newbie just started trying this out last night.
I was able to get geth up and running as well as ethminer. I woke up and when i did the check balance command it said i had 500000000 not sure how many zeros were actually there i know thats Wei. I had to shut my computer of and know when I check the balance it says zero. please help?

Thanks

Comment: How are you starting geth? Can you post your command line?

Comment: If you have your address then you can check your balance online in https://www.myetherwallet.com/. Sometimes geth will not return a correct balance if it is not completely synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why you receive different balance information. Looks like you are using some wallet-application and check balance using it. Then if you stop geth process, your wallet can not obtain any information about your account. Another reason can be - you are checking balance of the different accounts. Hard to say, your question is very unclear.